# How can I restore a deleted Sharepoint page?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

A colleague deleted a Sharepoint 2013 page by mistake, I can find it in the recycle bin, but when I try to restore it I encounter an error:

> A file named "P10.aspx" already exists in "PORG/OAN/Pages". To restore the file, rename the existing file and retry.

The fact is that when I go into "PORG/OAN", site content, Pages, I can't find any "P10.apsx". I also tried to search for an existing "P10.aspx" file on the entire Sharepoint and didn't find anything.

Does anyone have an idea where that file might be hidden or how to delete/rename it without finding it so I can restore the one in the recycle bin please?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Did you check the Site Collection recycle bin? Also, when was the file deleted? If it was more than 30 days ago it'll be dropped from the site recycle bin (default settings). If more than 60 days it will be completely gone (again, default settings).

Comment: Yes, it is in the Site Collection recycle bin, it was deleted on the 28/01, but when I try to restore it, I get an error saying that the file is already existing, but I can't find the "already existing file".

Comment: In the Pages library settings, click on "Manage files which have no checked in version" and check if the offending page is shown there.

Comment: Could you, by any chance, tell me how to get there, please? I'm pretty new to Sharepoint, they just pushed it on me...

Comment: Okay I found it, it's effectively in the files which have no checked in version, so I could take over it, rename it and restore the deleted one. Sadly, couldn't restore a proper version, he completely ruined it before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the Pages library settings, click on "Manage files which have no checked in version" and check if the offending page is shown there. –
> Monte_fisto